# Maintaining this context when linking a function to an event

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I have a set of functions that are contained within:

```
var main = {
    func1: function() {
        ...
    },
    func2: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

After the code, I have this line:

```
$('a.specialLink').click(main.func2);
```

Within the function, `func2`, there are references to the object via `this`, but when it is called from the onclick event, the `this` context is changed to the element that called it, rather than the object the function is within. Is there a way to return the `this` context to the main object? I know I can replace it with `main.`, but if I need to do similar things for instanciated objects, that wouldn't work.

The only thing I can think of so far would be to have the setup line replaced with this:

```
$('a.specialLink').click(function() { main.func2(main) });
```

where `func2` has an argument that is used as `this` (set to `this` if undefined), but that feels kind of messy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of so far would be to have the setup line replaced with this:
>
> ```
> $('a.specialLink').click(function() { main.func2(main) });
> ```

That's basically the way to do it. Yet, you can omit `main` as an argument, since when you call the function like this it already becomes the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
$('a.specialLink').click(function() { main.func2() });
```

However, instead of writing out that function expression you also could use the ES5.1 [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$('a.specialLink').click(main.func2.bind(main));
```

This will even implicitly pass-through all arguments, like the event object in this case.